# How to use CNContactPickerViewController to get address AND contact?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts-framework

I am trying to use the more modern `CNContactPickerViewController` to select a contact. If the contact has multiple addresses, I want the user to be able to select only one of the addresses. If an address is specifically selected, I want to also get the `CNContact` object as well.

I could do this using the deprecated `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`, where this delegate function was available:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(_ peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier)
```

However, when using `CNContactPickerViewController`, only this relevant delegate function is available:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty)
```

Note that there is no `CNContact` object returned. I get the `CNPostalAddress` in the contactProperty, but I don't receive the record of the owning contact.

Here's the code I used with `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`:

```
    let peoplePicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()

    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self

    peoplePicker.displayedProperties = [NSNumber(value: kABPersonAddressProperty as Int32), NSNumber(value: kABPersonBirthdayProperty as Int32)]

    peoplePicker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = NSPredicate(format: "postalAddresses.@count <= 1")

    peoplePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext

    self.present(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

...and here's the code with CNContactPickerViewController:

```
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()

    contactPicker.delegate = self

    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPostalAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey]

    contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "postalAddresses.@count <= 1")

    contactPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext

    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So, to me, it looks like the same functionality is no longer available in the newer Contacts Framework, but I'm checking here to see if I missed something.

Comment: My mistake was looking at the CNPostalAddress for a 'contact' property. Instead of looking at the contactProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that there is no `CNContact` object returned. I get the
>   `CNPostalAddress` in the contactProperty, but I don't receive the
>   record of the owning contact.

The `CNContact` object can be retrieved from the `contact` property of the `CNContactProperty`, so…

> However, when using `CNContactPickerViewController`, only this
>   relevant delegate function is available:
>
> ```
> func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty)
> ```

… implementing this delegate method would allow you to do what you want. But you want to make sure you're **not** implementing other delegate methods, such as:

```
func contactPicker(CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: CNContact)
```

which will dismiss the picker the moment a contact (and not its property) is selected.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that there is no CNContact object

You're just wrong about that. The delegate method is `contactPicker(_:didSelect:)`, it hands you a CNContactProperty, and the CNContactProperty hands you the whole CNContact and all its properties.